# Multiple Apache vHosts with same root directory issue

Tags: apache2.4

I have set up 2 virtual hosts in apache that look like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site 
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site 
</VirtualHost>
```

Both hosts point to the same document root. Each host is in its own .conf file. The issue I'm having is that example1.com loads without fail. But example2.com intermittently shows a 404 page not found. Refreshing several times finally loads the requested page but then after several more page refreshes, I get page not found again. I also have other vhosts setup, but they point to other directories. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Im closing this question. The problem was with apapche, I had to kill all processes as doing a restart dint work.

Comment: you should dump the headers each time w/ a commad-line client and show what accompanies the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Seems most likely to me that your example2.com has multiple DNS entries and one of them points to a different web server.